# How to set the color of the cursor(caret) multiple times in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

Lets say we have a simple EditText and I want to change the cursor(caret) to some other color, before we were use reflections to get access to the private fields, but with introduction of Android API Q(29), we can now use `textCursorDrawable` to set the drawable for the blinking cursor.

Here is the xml code of the EditText

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now we can use a WrapDrawable to wrap a ColorDrawable, that will be set as `textCursorDrawable` value of the EditText, in order for us to change the cursor color.

Here is the code for the WrapDrawable:

```kotlin
class WrapDrawable(color: Int) : Drawable() {

    private var drawable = ColorDrawable(color)

    @ColorInt
    var color: Int = color
        set(value) {
            field = value
            drawable = ColorDrawable(value)
        }

    override fun setBounds(left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
        drawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
    }

    override fun getConstantState(): ConstantState? {
        return drawable.constantState
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
        drawable.alpha = alpha
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(colorFilter: ColorFilter?) {
        drawable.colorFilter = colorFilter
    }

    override fun getOpacity(): Int {
        return drawable.alpha
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        drawable.draw(canvas)
    }

    override fun getIntrinsicWidth(): Int {
        return drawable.bounds.width()
    }

    override fun getIntrinsicHeight(): Int {
        return drawable.bounds.height()
    }
}
```

In the code below, we change the color of the cursor twice once to `Color.RED` and second time to `Color.BLUE`, now we should expect to have a BLUE cursor.
But the problem is that once ***textCursorDrawable*** is set, we cannot change it even if we try nullify it.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val text = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            // set the cursor color to RED
            text.textCursorDrawable = WrapDrawable(Color.RED).apply {
                setBounds(0, 0, 5, text.lineHeight)
            }
            
            // set the cursor color to BLUE !!! NOT WORKING !!!
            text.textCursorDrawable = WrapDrawable(Color.BLUE).apply {
                setBounds(0, 0, 5, text.lineHeight)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

### So my question is how can we reassign the `textCursorDrawable` value multiple times?

I have found a workaround by updating the already existing textCursorDrawable value, and changing the ColorDrawable using the color variable.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val text = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            // set the cursor color to RED
            text.textCursorDrawable = WrapDrawable(Color.RED).apply {
                setBounds(0, 0, 5, text.lineHeight)
            }

            // set the cursor color to BLUE
            text.textCursorDrawable?.let {
                if (it is WrapDrawable) {
                    it.color = Color.BLUE
                    it.setBounds(0, 0, 5, text.lineHeight)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `setTextCursorDrawable()` states:

> Note that any change applied to the cursor Drawable will not be visible until the cursor is hidden and then drawn again.

I have taken a quick look through the *TextView* and *EditText* code and haven't determined how to make the change you want. I am not saying that it can't be done; I just don't see it.

Instead, try making a change to your *WrapDrawable* like this:

```
(text.textCursorDrawable as WrapDrawable).apply {
    color = Color.BLUE
    setBounds(0, 0, 5, text.lineHeight)
}
```

This will work and will save the instantiation of a new *WrapDrawable*.

**Update**

Can't prove a negative, but it looks like the cursor drawable can't be replaced once set. The following is the reasoning.

For API 31, there are only two places within the *TextView* code where the cursor drawable is set. The private scope of `mCursorDrawable` will restrict outside access.

*In TextView.java:*

```
private Drawable mCursorDrawable;

public void setTextCursorDrawable(@Nullable Drawable textCursorDrawable) {  
    mCursorDrawable = textCursorDrawable;  
    mCursorDrawableRes = 0;  
    if (mEditor != null) {  
        mEditor.loadCursorDrawable();  
    }  
}

@Nullable public Drawable getTextCursorDrawable() {  
    if (mCursorDrawable == null && mCursorDrawableRes != 0) {  
        mCursorDrawable = mContext.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRes);  
    }  
    return mCursorDrawable;  
}
```

It is the text editor class that the cursor is drawn and it reaches back into the *TextView* to get the drawable that will be used.

*In Editor.java:*

```
Drawable mDrawableForCursor = null;

private void drawCursor(Canvas canvas, int cursorOffsetVertical) {  
    final boolean translate = cursorOffsetVertical != 0;  
    if (translate) canvas.translate(0, cursorOffsetVertical);  
    if (mDrawableForCursor != null) {  
        mDrawableForCursor.draw(canvas);  
    }  
    if (translate) canvas.translate(0, -cursorOffsetVertical);  
}

void loadCursorDrawable() {  
    if (mDrawableForCursor == null) {  
        mDrawableForCursor = mTextView.getTextCursorDrawable();  
    }  
}
```

`loadCursorDrawable` is the only place that `mDrawableForCursor` is set so, once it is defined, it can't be changed. Since it can't be changed, it can't be set to null to pick up a new cursor drawable that may be defined in the text view.

So, the long and the short of this is that the cursor can be changed in `TextView` but cannot be propagated to the editor.

Comment: I have already added this workaround in my question.

Comment: Oops! I don't know how I missed that. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to reset the cursor once it is set.  If I can find a way to explain what I have found, I will post it. In any case, the "work-around" is a better way to change the cursor color all else being equal. IMO

Comment: I have created a issue about this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249563008

Answer (score 0):

You can use LayeredDrawable and colorize its inner Drawable:

```
public static void setCursorColor(@NonNull EditText editText, int color) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Drawable drawable = editText.getTextCursorDrawable();
            if (!(editText.getTextCursorDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable))
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(editText.getContext(), R.drawable.edit_text_cursor_layer);
            try {
                GradientDrawable colorDrawable = (GradientDrawable) ((LayerDrawable) drawable).findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.cursor);
                colorDrawable.setColor(color);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            editText.setTextCursorDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

edit_text_cursor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

edit_text_cursor_layer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor" android:id="@+id/cursor"/>
</layer-list>
```