# How to dynamically change cursor color for EditText on Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a code.

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    StateListDrawable gradientDrawable = (StateListDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.cursor);
    DrawableContainer.DrawableContainerState drawableContainerState = (DrawableContainer.DrawableContainerState)gradientDrawable.getConstantState();
    Drawable[] children = drawableContainerState.getChildren();
    GradientDrawable selectedItem = (GradientDrawable)children[0];
    selectedItem.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    editText.setTextCursorDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

But it does not change color dynamically.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73867325/6287910) may help you.

Comment: Try looking at [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081602/16653700).